# Manhua/manhwa where the main character has a system which has dimensional powers, and travels between worlds

Tags: story-identification, manga, cultivation

Well, it's about maybe two years ago, but I badly want to read this manhua/manhwa.

In this, the main character (MC) has a cultivation system which has dimensional powers. The MC is transported from Earth to the cultivation world, and gets this system which helps in leveling ups his skills. There's a skill in which he make learn his enemy by which enemy got power, but when the MC needs, he can blow their heads. This system required the MC to travel to and clear different worlds to get system points and direct max up its skills.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Can you tell us anything more about the story, other than the fact that this is an isekai manhua/manhwa where the MC gets a system that allows and requires him to travel between worlds to level up his skills? In particular, I didn't understand the meaning of the following sentence: _"There's a skill in which he make learn his enemy by which enemy got power"_. Also, you only mentioned the MC. Can you describe any other characters in the story?

Answer (score 0):

I am an evil god...........Thank you

Comment: Good to see you figured out what you were looking for! However, to help people in the future who may be trying to find the same manga, could you [edit] in some more information to motiviate _why_ this is what you were looking for? A plot synopsis, or a brief description would be a great help. And don't forget to mark your answer as accepted!